# Equal height navigation bars

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have two pages in my app: One embedded in a `UINavigationController` and one thats not. The page that's not in the `UINavigationController` has a `UINavigationBar` that I dragged in and set its prompt to an empty string to increase its height a bit. However, this causes it to be slightly taller than the page that's embedded in a `UINavigationController`. Here's a side by side picture:

[image: pic]

If I set a prompt on the navigation bar of left page it's height becomes too tall. When I go to the storyboard inspector I see the height it should be is 74:

[image: pic2]

Does anybody know how to artificially make the bar on the page embedded in a `UINavigationController` the same height as the one that's not?

Answer (score 7):

This situation is common for others who added the `UINavigationBar` manually (i.e. not via embedding inside `UINavigationController`).

Generic `UINavigationBar` would have height of 44 points

The issue is the 20 points gap above the `manually added UINavigationBar`.

In the case of embedded version, the gap (assuming it exists) has the same background color as the `UINavigationBar`. When you add the prompt, it added 30 points expanding upward. So instead of 20 + 44 = 64 points, now you have 74 points.  And the `embedded UINavigationBar` has 64 points. Thus the difference of 10 points. And for the same reason, add " " (`space`) on `embedded UINavigationBar` will cause the height to be higher than `74 points`.

I think your best bet would be to also embed the other `ViewController` inside a `new UINavigationController`.  iOS is smart enough to treat it as if there is only one `NavigationController`, not two. The user would not experiencing any difference. As for the programmer, you need to take into account the `extra UINavigationController` if you need to find the `second ViewController` programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer my own question.

I just programmatically changed the height within a custom `UINavigationController` subclass:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let bounds = self.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 74)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put constraints in the UINavigationBar for height equals 64.
[image: storyboard capture]

Answer (score 1):

Navigartionbar have same constant size of 44. Either you embed it or use custom navigation. please check below image.

[image]

here I have embedded navigation in first and second is having custom one. There is no height issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although you've already answered your question, AFAIU the height difference is the result of having prompt in one case but not the other. So what is wrong with adding an empty string `prompt` for the ViewController inside `UINavigationController` using [`UINavigationItem`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624930-prompt) such as:

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = "";
```

If you have many view controllers inside your `UINavigationController` and don't want to set prompt explicitly in each, you can use [`UINavigationControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate) `willShow` or `didShow` event to set it in a single place for all child controllers.

This should be much more reliable than your approach because navigation bar height is not actually the same on all devices and all device orientations (AFAIR iPad portrait and landscape are different), moreover Apple can change it between iOS versions.

Comment: That will make the NavigationBar inside the NavigationController to be slightly higher than the one not in NavigationController. (off by 10 points).  It's the other way around the previous shorter now become a new higher.